# Can't open SharePoint link in Excel when trying to login using MS Account - "This operation has been canceled.."

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-10, sharepoint

When I try to open an online file hosted on SharePoint through Excel 2010 (application not online), it shows me the 'Login into Office 365' pop up.  I enter my hotmail address (for my MS account) into the email field and then it tries to redirect to the Microsoft Account Sign In Page.

But it then throws an error:
"This operation has been canceled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator."

I can open urls normally from within Excel.

The file can also be opened fine in the browser in Excel Online.

Windows 10, Excel 2010.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you navigate to the SharePoint site in the browser? It is unusual that you would use a MS account instead of a business account. Typically, SharePoint online would be run by a business and require authentication with the business 365 account, although it is possible to share files with MS account holders.

Comment: I can open it fine in the browser.  I don't have a 365 account and want to access a link that I received - surely a common occurrence.

Comment: Check the trust center settings in Excel, maybe and add the SharePoint site? Or make the file a trusted file.

Comment: Doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my machine had logged out of the MS Account in *Windows* after a password change. Simply logging in via the Windows popup fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps.

Run CMD as admin and then run the following commands:

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.htm /ve /d htmlfile /f
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.html /ve /d htmlfile /f
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.shtml /ve /d htmlfile /f
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.xht /ve /d htmlfile /f
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.xhtml /ve /d htmlfile /f
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately